# How to return EmployeeCode on angular employees component.html?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-core

**Problem**

How to return EmployeeCode on angular employees component.html ?

Sample data ReferenceTable

```
Code  tableName   FieldName   LabelText
111   Employees   EmployeeId  EmployeeCode
```

Result of calling

```
GetLabelTextForEmployee('Employees','EmployeeId')

it suppose Return EmployeeCode
```

I work on asp.net core 2.1 web API with angular 6.

I make function on web API name GetReferenceFileData to get text of label from

database and show on view on employees.component.html based on Reference Table .

This is my function :

```
[HttpGet("{tableName}/{FieldName}")]
        [Produces("text/plain")]
        public string GetReferenceFileData([FromRoute] string tableName, [FromRoute] string FieldName)
        {
          var Result =  (from h in _context.ReferenceFiles
                          where h.TableName == tableName && h.FieldName == FieldName
                          select h.LabelText).FirstOrDefault();
            if(Result==null)
            {
                Result = "Not Exist";
            }

            return (Result);


        }
```

Function above return only one string value for label as Scalar Value

What I have tried:

1- on API service I create Function Below :

```
GetLabelTextForEmployee(tableName:string,FieldName : string)
              {
                return this.http.get('https://localhost:44326/api/reference/' + tableName + '/' + FieldName);
              }


on employee.component.html
```

// how to use function GetLabelTextForEmployee here to return EmployeeCode
I make code according exist on post :

```
on employees.component.ts

    getEmployeeCode() {
       this.api.GetLabelTextForEmployee('Employees','EmployeeId')
       .subscribe( data=>{
         this.returnedData = data; //SUBSCRIBE HERE
         console.log(data);
       }); 
    }
on employees.component.html
 {{getEmployeeCode() | async}}
```

Result as below
I get EmployeeCode but in infinite loop and not show on form as image display
[Result of code on post infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVdJn.jpg)

Comment: can any one help me are there are any thing not clear

Comment: See my edits to see why you're in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean, when you call `GetLabelTextForEmployee()` you aren't getting a result (or rather, you aren't getting the result you expect)?

When you use Angular's `HttpClient` for HTTP requests, you **must** subscribe to the method, otherwise it is never actually executed.

In your `employee.component.ts`, you'l need to call the function, subscribe to it, and assign the result to a local variable. You can then use that local variable in your template (`employee.component.html`);

The following assumes you want to call the function on component initialisation, and your function is in a service call `ApiService`, and that your api returns an object.

**employee.component.ts**

```
employee: any;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    this.apiService.GetLabelTextForEmployee().subscribe(result => {
          this.employee = result;
    }
}
```

**employee.component.html**

Now, with your local variable assigned, you can use interpolation to display the value.

e.g

```
<span class="employee-code">{{employee.employeeCode}}</span>
```

Again, this is on the assumption your API returns an object, which you're accessing in the template with `{{employee.employeeCode}}`.

If your API returns a string, then you're simply interpolating `{{employee}}`

**EDIT**

If you want to call the function directly from the template, you still use interpolation, but as your function is in a service, you would need to have a function in your component which calls the service. It's not recommended to call a service function directly from the template.

i.e.

**employee.component.ts**

```
getEmployeeCode() {
    return this.apiService.GetLabelTextForEmployee('Employees','EmployeeId');
}
```

**employee.component.html**

Now, you can call `getEmployeeCode()` from your template, and use the `async` pipe.

`{{getEmployeeCode() | async}}`

**NOTE:** You do NOT need to subscribe to `GetLabelTextForEmployee()`in your component method (`getEmployeeCode()`) when using the `async` pipe. Angular will already subscribe to it, and return the latest value emitted, before marking for change detection.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Comment: thank you for reply on view if i need to call function GetLabelTextForEmployee

Comment: how to call function GetLabelTextForEmployee on employee.component.html Are calling will be {{GetLabelTextForEmployee}}

Comment: suppose i need to call it  on view GetLabelTextForEmployee('Employees','EmployeeId')'

Comment: I try code it return EmployeeCode but infinite loop and not show EmployeeCode on form can you please help me

Comment: @abeershlby You're subscribing inside your component method, and using the `async` pipe. You don't need to subscribe when using `async`, see edit for details.